# Ghost Text transformation on vertical scroll

Tags: html, css, text, css-transitions, css-transforms

while scrolling the page I need to load the ghost text effect when the specific section enters the screen or at least in the middle of screen but its showing effect when 80% of the section passes the screen vertically.

```js
const square = document.querySelector('.square');
square.classList.remove('square-transition');

// Create the observer, same as before:
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      square.classList.add('square-transition');
      return;
    }

    square.classList.remove('square-transition');
  });
});

observer.observe(document.querySelector('.square-wrapper'));
```

```css
.square {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.2;
  font-size: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 190px;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .square {
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease, transform 1.5s ease;
  }
}

.square-transition {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transform: translate3d(-10px, 0.2in, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="square-wrapper">
  <div class="square square-transition">Design Concept</div>
</div>
<div>........</div>
```

Comment: It's difficult to see the problem with this little code. Please show what the rest of the html looks like

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.